# Orion Context Broker - Subscriptions only notify the first 20 entities

Tags: fiware-orion

Using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

(curl http://orionip:1026/v1/subscribeContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'fiware-service: service' --header 'fiware-servicepath: /servicepath' \
 -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Sensor",
            "isPattern": "true",
            "id": "Parquimetro:.*"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        "recaudacion"
    ],
    "reference": "http://cometip:80/notify",
    "duration": "P4Y",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": [
                "recaudacion", "numeroTiques"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "throttling": "PT24H"
}
EOF
```

Makes a subscription for 170 entities (Parquimetro:1, Parquimetro:2, Parquimetro:3, ..., Parquimetro:170) to notify Comet for storing historical data, but only the first 20 entities got notified. I need it to notify all entities (which are right now 170, not 20).

Using `/v1/subscribeContext?limit=200` doesn't help either.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [an open issue at Orion github about it](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/591) from time ago.

Currently Orion behaves that way, but there is a workaround in place: do a (paginated) query to get all entities just before doing the subscription. It could happen some "race condition" if some update arrives since the query and the subscription, but, depending on the use case, it may suffice.

Comment: Even though the first query is lost for every entity but the 20 first, will the subscription work the rest of the time for all entities?